# removeFooterView at the bottom of the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that is populated from a web service. The list is pulled from JSON and is formatted through BaseAdapter. It is paginated.

So, if I request `http://example.com/item?page=2` it will append page 2 into the listview. I'm currently using `OnScrollListener` to request those pages. At the bottom of every pages is where I put a Footer view that displays **loading...** message.

However, at the last page of the ListView requested, the Loading message is still showing. I want it to be able to remove automatically.

Here is the Java code:

```
public class LatestFragment extends ListFragment implements OnScrollListener {

    private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
    private int currentVisibleItemCount;
    private int currentScrollState;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        mFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_loading, null);
        footerViewLayout = (RelativeLayout) mFooter.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);

        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        getListView().addFooterView(footerViewLayout, null, false);

        loadItemList(1);
    }

    private void loadItemList(int page) {
        // request URL
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
        this.isScrollCompleted();
    }

    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                currentPage++;
                loadItemList(currentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I put `.removeFooterView()` in this code to hide the Footer view after the List has no new items to show?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Improvements I made to the code. However, when it reaches the last page, I have to scroll down once to remove the FooterView since it can't automatically remove the FooterView. So far, this is a better solution to my question. But I can't tick it as solved :(

```
public class LatestFragment extends ListFragment implements OnScrollListener {

    private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
    private int currentVisibleItemCount;
    private int currentScrollState;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        mFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_loading, null);
        footerViewLayout = (RelativeLayout) mFooter.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);

        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        getListView().addFooterView(footerViewLayout, null, false);

        loadItemList(1);
    }

    private void loadItemList(int page) {

        if (page > 1) {
            if (lastKnownItemCount == currentItemCount){
                getListView().removeFooterView(footerViewLayout);
            }
        }

        lastKnownItemCount = currentItemCount;

        // request URL
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
        this.currentItemCount = listView.getCount();
        this.isScrollCompleted();
    }

    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            currentPage++;

            loadItemList(currentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks @Wizard for the idea. I'm hoping for a better solution to this.

Comment: you know how the total no. of items in listview

Comment: By using `listView.getCount()` in `OnScrollStateChanged()` method I suppose? Haven't tried it. I'm just stuck thinking how to go about writing the algorithm.

Comment: In my case i was knowing how many items going to come in listview and i did `if(knownitem== listviewitem) { .removeFooterView() }`

Comment: Dumb question, how do you store the value of the knownitem? Seems like a correct solution to my question here. Can you show the full implementation of your algo? Thanks.

Comment: m getting the data from the url where m getting total no of item (knownitems) when fetching the data i set the limit, before adding items to list we save the items in array, later  i compare the array size with knownitem

Comment: Updated my question with your idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loadItemList(int page) {
        // request URL
        if(page is the last page){
               removeFooterView
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I know which page is the last in the `if` statement?

Comment: that you have to know... I dont know where you are getting your data from (loadItemList is empty, you didnt give details). If you cant know if the page is the last page how can listview know!

Comment: you can check is data or page is empty or not